# In PowerPoint, is there a keyboard shortcut for bulleted / numbered list?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint

OneNote has two useful keyboard shortcuts for bulleted and numbered lists, namely <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>. Is there something similar for PowerPoint where the work with lists is also very common? Haven't found anything here: [Use keyboard shortcuts in PowerPoint](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-use-while-creating-a-presentation-in-powerpoint-2013-HA102749080.aspx).

Comment: which version of powerpoint ?

Comment: 2013 if that makes a difference

Answer (score 3):

As of PowerPoint 2016 the shortcut Alt+H, U will work and is slightly shorter.

Comment: It's so sad that even in 2022 there is no real shortcut build in. And you cannot do it on your own, too.
One extra hint I would like to offer, ist that you can add it to quickmenu on the top. then you have to press alt+<number> and once to the right followed by enter. Put this in a macro and you have worked your way around the Microsoft limitation...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just hit ALT, H, N, N to open the Bullets and Numbering dialog box.

You can then hit ALT + T to jump to the “start at” input box if you want.

These work regardless of your version of PPT.

If you want to see it demoed, watch the video on one of our blog posts here: https://nutsandboltsspeedtraining.com/create-continuous-numbering-across-your-objects/

(full disclosure: I run this website, but it's the only place I know that demoes this shortcut.)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[This microsoft page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-keyboard-shortcuts-to-create-powerpoint-presentations-ebb3d20e-dcd4-444f-a38e-bb5c5ed180f4#bkmk_formattext_win) lists powerpoint keyboard shortcuts for creating bullet point lists.

For regular filled bullets:

- type an **asterisk "*"** followed by a space character
- add the list entry text and press Enter

Replace the asterisk with other symbols for different list styles, e.g. ">" or "1.".